# When the MenuOptions screen is dismissed, the gray overlay is peeled out instead of immediately fade out

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I am using a High Frequency `LiveCard` with a `MenuActivity` as `PendingActivity` to handle Menu operations - Similar to many of the code samples for example here: 
https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-stopwatch-sample/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/glass/sample/stopwatch

Issue:

when the user taps on the Menu and then dismisses it (without selecting anything). The gray overlay on the top of the LiveCard should completely and instantly fade away, revealing the liveCard again. However, instead, I get an animation-like effect in which the gray overlay is slowly peeling out (from top to bottom).

Question: 
How can I make sure the gray overlay fades away instantly when the user dismisses the menu?

Below is the theme I use for the `MenuActivity`.

I appreciate your help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="MenuTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue.

Solution:

right after MenuActivity Finishes, I overrode the the exit animation to be fade_out.

Thanks

```html
finish();

// Changing the Activity's exit animation to fade_out
overridePendingTransition(0, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```